# How to track a specified program activity

Tags: windows, automation, monitoring, tracking, network-monitoring

I want track the behavior/activity of a specified program automatically and save them to a log file, for example i want to know:

- when it use network and on which address.
- which files it consulte/create.
- other command it execute.

....

is there a firewall that log all programs activities or a program that log files created/consulted by a specified program ?

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: @DavidPostill Thank you for your remark. But i am seeking a solution, a workaround, a method in the operating system or even a self implementable solution. I my last paragraph i just want to say it is not a problem if there is a program that do the trick.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx)

> Process Monitor is an advanced monitoring tool for Windows that shows
>   real-time file system, Registry and process/thread activity.

[This tool monitoring network activity also](https://askleo.com/how_to_monitor_network_activity_and_speed_up_your_machines_connection/).

Comment: Interesting, what about network activity?

Comment: @youzking Fiddler or Wireshark for network activity. Fiddler is for web requests and Wireshark is for general packet capture and flow.

Comment: Yes i thought about it but I want something automated, and that can be setup to track a specific program

Comment: I think Wireshark can do so, thank you @Narzard